# How to manage a variable length array in React state

Tags: reactjs, state

I may be thinking about this the wrong way, so I appreciate any redirection on my design.

I have a React component which gets a list in props.  The list can be from 0 to `n` in length.  I want to to manage an attribute of each list item in the state of the React component. (example below)  My gut tells me I'm doing something wrong, since I'm trying to set the state's value via props.

Is there a proper way to accomplish what I'm trying here?

```js
class MyList extends React.Component {
   state = {
     listItems: {}
   }

   render(){
     return(
        {this.renderListItems(this.props.list)}
   )

   renderListItems = list => {
      return list.map( listItem => {
        let id = listItem.id
        return <ListItem key={id} listItem={listItem} color={this.state.listItems[id].color} />
   }

}
```

Comment: "since I'm trying to set the state's value via props", where you doing that in this snippet? as far we can tell you will always get runtime error because `listItems[id].color` is undefined.

Comment: Nope, you are doing it fine !! As long as the logic of `color` is owned by `MyList` component, this is fine.

Comment: @DennisVash That's just it, since I could have 1, 5, or even 50 list items, I have no initial values for this.state.listItems.  Essentially, I need to get them into state somehow.  I think... :)

Comment: Your question is unclear, you can initiate your state with props

Comment: @DennisVash I know I *can* set state from props, but should I? I thought it was an antipattern to set initial state from props, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Its not an anti pattern